# Accessing elements of cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

A rather simple question. I have a matrix `mask`

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(20, 25, CV_8UC1);
```

and a point `pt`

```
cv::Point pt(5,7);
```

How can I access an element of `mask` at the location `pt` (at 5-th row and 7-th column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char value = mask.at<char>(pt);
```

Comment: should the variable type be `uchar` or `char`?

Comment: thanks. looked it up - `CV_8UC1` is an opencv type for unsigned 8-bit single-channel data

Comment: Yes, and the `char` in the template function `cv::Mat::at()` is used to calculate the offset of a specific value from the beginning of the Mat's data.